How to remove a navigation banner from Wordpress website using Elementor add on?
I am new to website design and am editing a Wordpress website using Elementor.
I am having an issue where this " > Home > Work" banner appears when I preview my website, but not in the Elementor editor itself. I do not want this banner to appear on the live site -- does anyone know how to fix this?
Elementor editor view
Preview view
I've tried removing the container this banner is in, but that did not resolve the discrepancy.
I also tried inspecting the page and finding the code that is causing this banner to appear in the preview but could not find anything that seemed to be responsible for its presence. Again, I am new to webpage design, so maybe there is something I am missing here.
Any thoughts/guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!]

Update (12/23/24 12:03 pm):
I believe I located the CSS code responsible for the unwanted banner. However, when I click 'delete element', it still appears when I refresh the page.
Inspect Code

" > Home > Work" is only there in preview (to let you know you are pre-viewing) ?   About your last update: when you make a change vi inspect, the change is only temporary, until the next refresh..... (That why it's named inspect, and not change )

Thanks @Luuk! To answer your question - yes, "Home > Work " is only there in preview, and does not appear when I am in the editor window

It is better to use WP Stack Exchange

You need to find and turn off "Breadcrumbs" settings.
In Elementor, open the page you want to edit, find the "Breadcrumbs" widget, and then toggle the visibility setting to "Hide" within the widget settings.
If you cannot find Breadcrumbs settings there, try locating it inside your current Theme's customizer settings.
Additionally, this resource might be helpful to you -
https://elementor.com/help/breadcrumbs-widget-pro/

Thanks for the tip! When I am in Elementor, the page appears how I want it to display live, in these sense that I do not see the "> Home > Work" breadcrumbs nor the Breadcrumbs widget in the Structure pane. These breadcrumbs only appear when I preview the page.
